# React with Laravel deployment Cache issue

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, laravel-mix, react-laravel

I have created an app with react and laravel, whenever made an update and deploy it, the client browser does not update the cahnges, it always load from the cache. When I am using in an incognito window or cleared the browser cache the changes reflected.

I have tried clearing npm cache as well as php artisan cache clean, It doesnt work out for me.

What should I do to clear the browser cache whenever I update the code?

Thank you in advance,
Vicky

Comment: Add this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/classic-cache-killer/kkmknnnjliniefekpicbaaobdnjjikfp) in your browser

Answer (score 0):

Running `npm run prod` should re-generate assets with the proper versioning to solve the cache issue.